# How to deal with childhood trauma effectively?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, personality

What can we do as adults to rectify childhood damages? 
For instance, When as an adult one feels lonely, anxious,etc ... at many occasions, I believe there is a good chance that those feelings are rooted in the person's childhood. Once it is diagnosed what the feelings come from originally, how can it be dealt with?

Comment: Hi Maryam. Thanks for the question! On CS we tend to not answer "self-help" questions, for a series of reasons. Is there any way you could rephrase this more generally, with some examples from other people included? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @mfloren. Thanks for the advice. I tried changing it. Is it still not acceptable because I see it is still on hold.

Comment: I have voted to re-open this question as it is possible to answer.  I will try to keep an eye on whether this gets re-opened, and if it does I will provide an answer within the group accepted and professional guidelines which hopefully will help.

Comment: Of course! Once a question is put on hold it has to be "re-opened": with enough votes, it should be taken off of hold. I'm also voting to re-open.

Comment: Thanks @Chris and mfloren. Hopefully This post can get enough vote to be active again :)

Comment: Not sure if my question is ever going to be active again, I found this https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/9661/how-do-some-traumatic-experiences-establish-deep-beliefs-and-ideas?rq=1. It might help people who were interested in the answer.